# Did Montag ever have rebellious thoughts before meeting Clarisse?

Tags: fahrenheit-451, ray-bradbury

In *Fahrenheit 451*, Montag questions the society he lives in after meeting a mysterious neighbor who encourages Montag to think and read, two thing forbidden in the dystopian world. He catches on rather quickly, prompting the question:

**Did Montag have rebellious thoughts before meeting with Clarisse?**

*Note: In this question I am looking for something (quote) from either the book or Ray Bradbury.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Montag committed at least one *lapse* prior to meeting Clarisse, about a year earlier when he encountered an old man in the park. In addition to listening to  a poetry reading (not in and of itself a crime, but certainly considered aberrant behaviour) he failed to search the Professor despite being confident that he'd find a book of poetry on the man.

> *They had sat in the green soft light without saying a word for a moment and then Montag talked about the weather and then the old man
>   responded with a pale voice. It was a strange quiet meeting. The old
>   man admitted to being a retired English professor who had been thrown
>   out upon the world forty years ago when the last liberal arts college
>   shut for lack of students and patronage. His name was Faber, and when
>   he finally lost his fear of Montag, he talked in a cadenced voice,
>   looking at the sky and the trees and the green park, and when an hour
>   had passed he said something to Montag and Montag sensed it was a
>   rhymeless poem.*
>
> *Then the old man grew even more courageous and said something else and that was a poem, too. Faber held his hand over his left coat
>   pocket and spoke these words gently, and **Montag knew if he reached
>   out, he might pull a book of poetry from the man’s coat. But he did
>   not reach out.** His hands stayed on his knees, numbed and useless. “I
>   don’t talk things, sir,” said Faber. “I talk the meaning of things. I
>   sit here and know I’m alive.”*

You may wish to note that senior Firemen, aware of the constant presence of temptation to which their men are subject, will often turn a blind eye to relatively severe transgressions (such as the taking *and reading* of the books that they're expected to burn).

> *“Well, then, what if a fireman accidentally, really not intending anything, takes a book home with him?”
>
>   Montag twitched. The open door looked at him with its great vacant eye.
>
>   **“A natural error. Curiosity alone,” said Beatty. “We don’t get overanxious or mad. We let the fireman keep the book twenty-four hours.** If he hasn’t burned it by then, we simply come burn it for him.”
>
>   “Of course.” Montag’s mouth was dry.*